# Install Linux with two hard drives

Tags: linux, installation, ubuntu-12.04, hard-drive

I've a machine with two hard drives. The first one has 80 GB and the second has 120 GB. I'm about to format this machine and install Linux, and I want to install all the main partitions (`/`, `/boot`, `/usr/`, etc.) on the first hard disk drive (`sda`) and mount the `/home` and `/var` partition on second disk (`sdb`).

Is this possible, and do I have to do something after the instalation? Or is the second hard disk drive automatically mounted? How can I do it?

I won't do it, but is there any problem to mount `/boot` on the second hard disk drive?

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

This will be something you have to do post-installation since the Ubuntu installer does not include that feature. I hate to refer to an outside source, but an excellent guide on how to do this has already been written, *[HOW TO: Create a separate /home partition](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=9141619)*. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Your first question has already been answered by gluxon so no need for me to repeat it but regarding the second question -

Yes, it should be technically possible to mount /boot from a different drive, although you will need to modify the GRUB command line to reflect that, because the /boot partition by definition has the kernel image and the initramfs.

Obviously it is not recommended. If the root FS partition (/), boot partition (/boot) and GRUB are not all on the same disk then if either disk fails your machine will not boot.